# React Redux-saga, реализация поиска, пагинация результата поиска

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

Сама идея: посты подгружаются порционно с помощью пагинации c параметрами запроса ?_page=1&_limit=10. Поиск подгружает все данные и выводит отфильтрованный массив. Прошу помочь в работе с логикой работы с сагой. Как разделить эти два метода работы с данными. При пустом поиске должен запускаться GET_POSTS, при любом значение поиска GET_SEARCH

Reducer

```
import { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  GET_POSTS,
  GET_POSTS_ERROR,
  GET_POSTS_SUCCESS,
  GET_SEARCH,
  GET_SEARCH_SUCCESS,
  GET_SEARCH_ERROR,
} from "../contstants";

import { initialStateType, PostsType } from "../../types/types";

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  query: "",
  totalCount: 0,
  loadingPosts: false,
  error: false,
  postPerPage: 10,
} as initialStateType;

const PostsReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  { type, payload }: PayloadAction<any>
) => {
  switch (type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      state = { ...state, loadingPosts: true };
      break;
    case GET_POSTS_SUCCESS:
      state = {
        ...state,
        posts: payload.data,
        totalCount: payload.headers["x-total-count"],
        loadingPosts: false,
      };
      break;
    case GET_POSTS_ERROR:
      state = {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        loadingPosts: false,
      };
      break;

     case GET_SEARCH:
      state = {
        ...state,
        query: payload,
        loadingPosts: true,
      };
      break;
    case GET_SEARCH_SUCCESS:
      let newstate = payload.data.filter((v: PostsType) => {
        return v.title.toLowerCase().includes(state.query);
      });
      state = {
        ...state,
        posts: newstate,
        loadingPosts: false,
      };
      break;
    case GET_SEARCH_ERROR:
      state = {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        loadingPosts: false,
      };
      break;

    default:
      state = { ...state };
      break;
  }

  return state;
};

export default PostsReducer;
```

Saga

```
import { put, call, takeLatest, all, fork } from "redux-saga/effects";

import {
  GET_POSTS,  
  GET_SEARCH,
} from "../contstants";
import {
  getPostsError,
  getPostsSuccess,
  getSearchSuccess,
  getSearchError,
} from "../actions/actionCreator";

import {
  getPosts,
  getSearch,
} from "../../helpers/backend_helper";


function* onGetPosts({ payload: _page, _limit }: any): any {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getPosts, _page, _limit);
    yield put(getPostsSuccess(response));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getPostsError(error.response));
  }
}


function* onGetSearch({ payload: search }: any): any {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getSearch, search);
    yield put(getSearchSuccess(response));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getSearchError(error.response));
  }
}

function* watchSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_POSTS, onGetPosts);
  yield takeLatest(GET_SEARCH, onGetSearch);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([fork(watchSaga)]);  
}
```

Action

```
import {
  GET_POSTS,
  GET_POSTS_SUCCESS,
  GET_POSTS_ERROR,
  GET_SEARCH,
  GET_SEARCH_SUCCESS,
  GET_SEARCH_ERROR,
} from "../contstants";

import { PostsType } from "../../types/types";

export const getPosts = (_page: any, _limit: any) => ({
  type: GET_POSTS,
  payload: _page,
  _limit,
});

export const getPostsSuccess = (posts: PostsType) => {
  return {
    type: GET_POSTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: posts,
  };
};
export const getPostsError = (error: boolean) => {
  return {
    type: GET_POSTS_ERROR,
    payload: error,
  };
};

export const getSearch = (search: string) => {
  return {
    type: GET_SEARCH,
    payload: search,
  };
};

export const getSearchSuccess = (posts: PostsType) => {
  return {
    type: GET_SEARCH_SUCCESS,
    payload: posts,
  };
};
export const getSearchError = (error: boolean) => {
  return {
    type: GET_SEARCH_ERROR,
    payload: error,
  };
};
```